# Why toast doesn't appear in the cellphone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a really simple and strange question. I have this line of code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ToastAndroid.show("Test", ToastAndroid.LONG);
  }, []);
```

My expected result is to see a toast when the page is loading. But it doesn't happen. Neither on the simulator nor the real cellphone.

Any idea what's the possible issues?

Comment: this links works for me. https://snack.expo.dev/294FyBd2s , can you share me your entire code?

Comment: @GauravRoy thanks for providing that link, but I know how to use Toast, I've already done that, but I have no idea why it doesn't work inside an specific component

Comment: i guess some issue with your code, share the entire snippet please